# How to transform all pixels of an RGB image to HLS image in linear time by using colorsys.rgb_to_hls in python?

Tags: python, arrays, image, lambda, rgb

Say there is an image data pixels with size of 1000px*1000px in rgb style.
Its data structrue is numpy's array, 1000*1000*3 and the rgb is in [0,1] and is float.
You can turn this array back into image if you need using

```
image = Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(pixels*255))
```

I already knew using colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r,g,b) could transform one pixel to hls, but in this case, I wanna know if there is any other way to transform the whole pixels in one sentence like this:

```
image.point(lambda i: colorsys.rgb_to_hls(i))
```

I failed using this because: rgb_to_hls takes 3 individual params and i represents only r/g/b in one time.

**_______________________Edit 2014 05 28 10:34 am_____________________________**

My fault, double loop is doable but its time cost is unbearable in python as python's loop is too slow.

**_______________________Edit 2014 05 28 10:57 am_____________________________**

```
rows, cols = pixels.shape[0], pixels.shape[1]

# transpose to 3 * pixels_number
# utilized for extract R/G/B cols

t_p = pixels.swapaxes(0, 2).swapaxes(1, 2)
R, G, B = t_p[0], t_p[1], t_p[2]

dRG, dRB, dGB = R - G, R - B, G - B
temp = 2*numpy.sqrt(dRG**2+dRB*dGB)
mskTemp = (temp == 0.0)
temp[mskTemp] = 1.0
# Hue
cos = (dRG+dRB)/(temp)
H = numpy.arccos(cos) # 0.08
# check for gray_scale
H[mskTemp] = 0.0
# check for nan value
H[numpy.isnan(H)] = 0.0
# Intensity = r+g+b / 3
I = pixels.mean(axis = 2)
# prepare for Saturation calc
Imin = pixels.min(axis = 2)
I[I == 0.0] = 0.01
S = 1 - Imin / I
```

and it costs 0.289 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to apply the `colorsys.rgb_to_hls` to each pixel, why not loop over the array?

```
pixels_hls = np.zeros_like(pixels)

for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(1000):
        pixels_hls[i,j,:] = np.array(colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*pixels[i,j,:]))
```

Comment: This may be too slow for my app.

Comment: If you are concerned with performance, you should try to profile it.

Comment: I just tried and it costs almost 20 seconds... What I prefer would be a matrix op other than a double-loop. You know python do matrix much better than loop.

Comment: My implementation is updated in my question, thank you.